# как увеличивать номер элемента( [0] ) в списке на 1 тобиш он станет( [1] )

Tags: python, tkinter

вот пример который я пытаюсь упростить

```
global image
if listbox1.curselection()[0] == 0:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="0.png")
            lab.config(image=image)
   elif listbox1.curselection()[0] == 1:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="1.png")
            lab.config(image=image)
   elif listbox1.curselection()[0] == 2:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="2.png")
            lab.config(image=image)
   elif listbox1.curselection()[0] == 3:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="3.png")
            lab.config(image=image)
    elif listbox1.curselection()[0] == 4:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="4.png")
            lab.config(image=image)
    elif listbox1.curselection()[0] == 5:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="5.png")
            lab.config(image=image)
    elif listbox1.curselection()[0] == 6:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="6.png")
            lab.config(image=image)
    elif listbox1.curselection()[0] == 7:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="7.png")
            lab.config(image=image)
    elif listbox1.curselection()[0] == 8:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="8.png")
            lab.config(image=image)
    elif listbox1.curselection()[0] == 9:
            image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="9.png")
            lab.config(image=image)
```

А вот что у меня вышло

```
        global image
        list=[
                "0.png","1.png","2.png",
                "3.png","4.png","5.png",
                "6.png","7.png","8.png","9.png"

              ]
        a = listbox1.curselection()[0]

        for i in range(10):
           if a == i:
              image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=list)
              lab.config(image=image)
```

`image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=list)` теперь мне место `list` надо сделать так что бы номер элемента тобишь начинающегося с `[0]` увеличивался на 1.
Так как у меня всё это в цикле надо просто чтобы номер элемента списка увеличивался на один раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему нельзя просто

```
a = int(listbox1.curselection()[0])

if a >= 0 and a < 10:
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=list[a])
    lab.config(image=image)
```

?

Comment: Да потому что не работает

Comment: А сконвертировать в int?

Comment: это ничего не поменяет там и так int

Comment: Тогда очень странное утверждение. Что именно не работает, и как именно оно не работает?

Comment: Ошибочка вышла. Очень сильно извеняюсь, не заметил кое что. Всё работает отлично, извеняюсь ещё раз, неловко вышло как-то

Comment: Ну и славно! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
        global image
        list=[
                "0.png","1.png","2.png",
                "3.png","4.png","5.png",
                "6.png","7.png","8.png","9.png"

              ]
        a = listbox1.curselection()[0]

        for i in range(10):
           if a == i:
              image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=list[i])
              lab.config(image=image)
```